# Select related foreign key value in the dropdown menu in the Add/Change page of Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Album(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Video(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    src = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

As show above, in the Video Admin add/change page, there are two dropdown menu for selecting: Album and Doctor.

However, when I choose an Album (e.g. album.id=1 and belongs to doctor.id=5), the Doctor dropdown menu display all Doctors, but I only wanna the only one who related to the Album that I choose.

I tried [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), it didn't work.
And, I add autocomplete_fields = ['doc'] under class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin), it didn't work too.

Anyone can give me a hand? Thanks VEry veRY much!

Comment: I find it rather strange that you let a user select the `doc` here anyway. If it is the same as the `doc` of the `Album`, then you are *injecting* data duplication: if later the `doc` on the album changes, it will *not* change the `doc` of the video, so personally I would simply remove the `doc` from video, and reference it through `self.album.doc`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What I wanna is automatically selecting the doc. Yes, for the change page, you are right. But in the add new video page, if a user chooses  an album (which means the video that he/she going to add is belong to this album) he/she doesn't need to choose the doc since it's already bind in the album model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way which is overriding the change_form.html of the Admin to add some jQuery code to accomplish it.

/PROJECT_DIR/templates/admin/APP_NAME/MODEL_NAME/change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %} 
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }} 
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $( "select#id_aid" ).change(function() {
                $.getJSON("/api/getAlbumRelatedDoc/",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j){ 
                        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { 
                            options = '<option value="' + j[i].doc + '">' + j[i].doc__name + '</option>'; 
                        }
                        $("select#id_doc").html(options); 
                        $("span#select2-id_doc-container").html(j[0].doc__name)
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

/PROJECT_DIR/APP_NAME/views.py

```
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def get_album_relate_doc(request): 
        id = request.GET.get('id','') 
        result = list(Album.objects.filter(id=int(id)).values('doc', 'doc__name')) 
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

/PROJECT_DIR/APP_NAME/urls.py

```
path('getAlbumRelatedDoc/', views.get_album_relate_doc),
```

BTW, I'm using django-jet as the admin replacement.